# C# Winform size reduced in reduced resolution

Tags: c#, .net, resolution-independence

I have a pretty simple c# application that uses .net framework 2.0.  In my development machine (which is set to 1024x768) the app appears fine.  The client runs the application in 1024x600 netbook, and the form seems like it's reduced in height.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/381953/Screen%20shot%202010-11-01%20at%204.51.01%20PM.png

I tried to simulate the environment in VMWare, under 1004x601 resolution the app still looks fine.

Is there something I'm missing that would cause the window hight to be reduced?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's not the windows who is reduced: take a look with the font size of the system, and all the theming system...

Can you post a print screen of the original window please ?

And please, can you repost you picture with 1:1 scale ?

Answer (score 2):

Set the `AutoScaleMode` property on the form and on any custom user control to `None`. Default is set to `Font`.

Comment: If he do so, it's the text that will not fit in the controls, isn't it ?

Comment: If you set the property to None, then the size of everyhitng contained in the window will remain the same with the size in the development resolution and DPI settings. Kind of "what you see is what you get".